# Operators ['~','!~'] in filter[website1] are not supported

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

I want to retrieve leads using web API. 
I used http:///admin/api/leads?filter[website1]~ but recieved

```
[{"title":"filter constraint","detail":"The operator \"contains\" is not supported.","source":"filter[website1]"}]
```

I added to /vendor/oro/crm/src/Oro/Bundle/SalesBundle/Resources/config/oro/api.yml a new filter: 
   to 
    `Oro\Bundle\SalesBundle\Entity\Lead:
         filters:` 
section I added a new filter `website1`:
   `website1:
       data_type: string
       allow_array: true
       options:
           case_insensitive: true
       operators: ['=', '!=', '*', '!*', '~', '!~', '^', '!^', '$', '!$']` 
after that I successfylly ran

```
php bin/console oro:api:cache:clear
```

and can see this filter in filters section when run `php bin/console oro:api:config:dump users`

```
 website1:
            allow_array: true
            options:
                case_insensitive: true
            operators:
                - eq
                - neq
                - exists
                - neq_or_null
                - contains
                - not_contains
                - starts_with
                - not_starts_with
                - ends_with
                - not_ends_with
            data_type: string
```

But anyway the response states that "contains" operator is not supported.
What I'm doing wrong? and how to make filter use this operator and ^ operator etc.

Comment: Hi Natalia, Which version of OroCommerce do you use?

Comment: Also, there is a mistake in a message, you updated the lead entity, but dump configuration for the user entity.